# Save Word document as new file but keep old document opened

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

The usual way Word acts, when saving a Word document with a new filename, is to change the active document from the old filepath to the new filepath.
So from now on all changes are saved to the new filepath.

But I want to keep the document of the old filepath opened in Word.

Is there an elegant way to do that?

At the moment i do it like this (Saving 3 times):

```
private void OnWordFileChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    WordService.SaveAsNewFilename();
    WordService.SaveAsOldFilename();
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pranavwagh/2008/04/03/how-to-do-a-save-copy-as-in-word/ try this

Comment: You are right @JohnG: I would like to keep the document opend in Word not the file path as a string.